# mysql INSERTs back to back are failing randomly

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I have tried almost everything I knew but not able to fix this rather weird set of bugs.

I am trying to make 4 INSERTs in a message que table.

$email_start_message, $sms_start_message, $email_end_message and $sms_end_message are strings stored as blobs as in future they will have HTML and images.

The code is below:

```
$response = array();

$send_status = 0;

$seller_id = 1275;

$re1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pos_msg_que(send_status, sid, uid, alert_type, alert_data, send_time) VALUES ('$send_status','$seller_id','$uid','1','mysql_real_escape_string($email_start_message)','$start_time');");

if (!$re1 == 'false') {
  $response['start_email_alert'] =  '1';
} else {
  $response['start_email_alert'] =  '0';
}

$re2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pos_msg_que(send_status, sid, uid, alert_type, alert_data, send_time) VALUES ('$send_status','$seller_id','$uid','2','mysql_real_escape_string($sms_start_message)','$start_time');");

if (!$re2 == 'false') {
  $response['start_sms_alert'] =  '1';
} else {
  $response['start_sms_alert'] =  '0';
}

$re3 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pos_msg_que(send_status, sid, uid, alert_type, alert_data, send_time) VALUES ('$send_status','$seller_id','$uid','3','mysql_real_escape_string($email_end_message)','$end_time');");

if (!$re3 == 'false') {
  $response['end_email_alert'] =  '1';
} else {
  $response['end_email_alert'] =  '0';
}

$re4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pos_msg_que(send_status, sid, uid, alert_type, alert_data, send_time) VALUES ('$send_status','$seller_id',  '$uid','4','mysql_real_escape_string($sms_end_message)','$end_time');");

if (!$re4 == 'false') {
  $response['end_sms_alert'] =  '1';
} else {
  $response['end_sms_alert'] =  '0';
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

}

The table structure is:

```
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field           | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id              | int(8)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| send_status     | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| sid             | int(8)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| uid             | int(8)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| alert_type      | tinyint(2) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| alert_data      | blob       | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| send_time       | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| advance_time    | int(3)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| last_attempt_at | timestamp  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Now when I run this code, the JSON response is:

> {"start_email_alert":"1 0","start_sms_alert":"0
>   12","end_email_alert":"1 12","end_sms_alert":"1 12"}

The issues are:

1. The 1st Insert always gets insert ID 0
2. The 2nd Insert is always failing, but the ID is autoincremented
3. The 3rd and 4th Insert is happening but the ID used is that of step 2, so effectively they overwrite.
4. For reasons I cant figure out, the alert_type always shows 1 in DB. Though I am inserting 2,3 literally.

Can someone help me figure this out please?

Comment: Whoever can follow this, is a God.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am sorry, should I explain the code more?

Comment: Start at the beginning because first auto_increment value is `1`, not `0`. `mysql_insert_id()` response of `0` is an error.

Comment: It looks like you are not using the built-in error reporting with the MySQL API in PHP. Basic usage: `$response = mysql_query([QUERY]) or trigger_error(mysql_error());`. Documentation for `mysql_error()` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php. Also, the formatting of your code is quite difficult to read.

Comment: I'm dyslexic actually, and seeing a whole bunch of dots all over the place like that, confuses me. Sort of like Morse code `. "', '" .`

Comment: As with most query issues, I would start by printing the query to the html page and copying it into phpmyadmin  or  mysql command line to make sure there are't error's in the actual query string.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I didnt get you. The first auto increment value is 0 as per the response - {"start_email_alert":"1 0". From the second Insert, the correct Auto increment value is picked.

Comment: @Jasper - Thanks. I didnt know it. Will read up and incorporate.

Comment: I couldn't duplicate your `AUTO_INCREMENT` issues from Workbench. You might find this easier to troubleshoot (and we would all find it easier to understand) if you followed best practices by 1) using [mysqli](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead of the deprecated mysql extension, and 2) parameterizing your insert queries instead of hard-coding the values to be inserted.

Comment: @Jasper Thanks again. Helped me nail the issue. The strings had single-quotes, which were not escaping for some weird character encoding issue. Wrote a separate function(shared in answer) and it was fixed.

Comment: @AirThomas Thanks. The code was correct, the trouble was with the strings(which I assumed were good). The strings were not appropriately escaped. Sharing the answer below.

Nevertheless, using your suggestion, I parameterized the query and formatted the code. Helped me fix it faster. Thanks. I will adopt the code to PDO soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being downvoted twice and favorited once, I was perplexed as to what's so wrong with the code. Thanks to @AirThomas and @Jasper, I formatted the code and adopted some best practices, which helped me nail the issue.

The issue was with the strings. They had single quotes and were somehow not getting escaped (mostly, due to some weird character encoding trouble. I didn't bother to get into details). Rather used a simple function from ([phpfreaks](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/279149-mysql-real-escape-string-not-escaping-single-quotes/)) to ensure, I am not leaving any stone unturned while escaping. The function is:

```
function cleanStr($str){
  $str = trim($str);
  if($str == "") return;

  $str = stripslashes($str);//STRIP \ slashes
  if (function_exists(mysqli_real_escape_string)){
    $str = mysqli_real_escape_string($str);
  }else{
    $str = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
  }
  //CONVERT TO HTML
  $str = htmlspecialchars($str);
  //LAST CLEAN UP
  $str = preg_replace("#\'#","",$str);
  return $str;
}
```

After escaping the strings and parametrizing the code (edited the question to show the latest code), the inserts worked like a charm.

Things I learnt today:

- Escape the strings properly, not just mysql_real_escape_string
- Use mysql_error() like so to catch mysql errors.

> echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "\n";

- Format the query and parametrize it as much as possible
- Format the code properly before posting on SO, else you dont even
- Use PDO or mysqli

I have just started coding (4 weeks back), so apologies for the obvious errors.

Thanks everyone